# How do I understand Ni (you) character correctly?

Tags: character-components

It says

[image]

http://zhongwen.com/bushou.htm

If I search for you I got this

It consists of 2 characters

The first is person and you. The 2 characters are very different than the character in character ni. I supposed the ren is in alternate version. I wonder what's the character next to it.

It says there that the character next to it is you.

However, clicking it says it's the character er which means breath.

[image]

Of course, the character breath itself consist of 2 characters.

The upper part is ru (enter). And below we have number 8 pa divided by vertical line.

How wrong I am? Please correct me.

Any idea why letter 8 under enter becomes breath that combined with men becomes "you"? Any website that explains this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Outlier*

> **FORM**
>   你 consists of 尔 (a shorthand form of 爾 “you”), and 亻 (person), indicating the original meaning “you.” 尔 also gives the sound.
>   [Reference, p. 1253]
>
> **COMPONENTS**
>    亻
>   In 你, 亻“person” is a meaning component, indicating “having to do with people.”
>    尔
>   In 你 nǐ, 尔 ěr is both a meaning component and a sound component. It is shorthand for 爾, an ancient character that meant “you” (among other things). The sound connection between 你 nǐ and 尔 ěr is not obvious in modern Mandarin.

Comment: Please tell me your source?

Comment: @user4951 I wrote it at the very top of my answer, but here’s a link if that’s more helpful: https://www.outlier-linguistics.com/collections/chinese/products/outlier-dictionary-of-chinese-characters

Answer (score 0):

On his blog SinoSplice the linguist John Pasden wrote an article about [Challenges to Character Understanding](https://www.sinosplice.com/life/archives/2020/04/01/challenges-to-character-understanding) where he explains the understanding of character `你` (nǐ).

He showed his source of **Outliers Dictionary** (add-on to the free app Pleco):
[image: Outliers Dictionary on Ni]