# What's the meaning of the hat like character on top of 尔

Tags: character-components

According to https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%B0%94#Chinese

It is

this character https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%BA%88

It simply means knife but the wiktionary entry is very short.

Google translate says that it's meaning is indeed knife and it's read Dao.

However,

According to http://zhongwen.com/bushou.htm

[image]

The hat character is ru that means enter. So which one is right?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it comes from a misunderstanding of the character structure.

Comment: @dROOOze Didn't you answer almost exactly this question a few weeks ago?

Comment: @OlleLinge the OP asked 3 variations of questions on the character 尔, I chose to answer what I thought was the most sensible question. Since this question does not have satisfactory attention, it was bumped. I suggest we vote to close it.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Voted.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think it's a knife. Maybe a handle??

尔 variant of 爾｜尔

warping-wheel-er 尔爾 ěr (weaving not my strong point, not really sure what that is)

尔 seems to be the top part of 爾

Original meaning 本义: Meaning (orig) a rolled up spindle (now) meaning you.

你
Character decomposition 字形分解 [?]: 
Compound 你 older 儞

from person-left-ren 亻人 rén and

related phonetic warping-wheel-er 尔爾 ěr.

Answer (score 0):

Both are right. 尒 is a variant of 尔, which is not used in modern Chinese any more. They just have different components on the top. Different components mean different things. Maybe you can see 尒 in vintage books.